# how do I get back my deleted folder? my recover software give me tmp file, not the folder

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally (shift+del) deleted a folder in desktop. so I recover my desktop folder. I recover the folder using third party application. it took about three hour to scan the deleted file.

and this is I got.

[image: Recovered files and folder]

The files are correct,and everything work. 
but i can't find the folder.

and i am sure the deleted folder have to somewhere between `~WRL1987.tmp` and `~WRL1987-8.tmp` because the size of the file is same with the folder that i have deleted.

how to get back my folder?

Comment: If the sectors were overwritten by some other file after you deleted that folder, then it is un recoverable. Once a file is deleted past the recycle bin the system may use that the free space to store something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to try another piece of software, such as Recuva

If that also fails then it's likely not recoverable. Your only option is to send to a specialist but either way, this is a lesson as to why we take back ups!!!

Answer (score -1):

the third party application recover by files, not folder directly. to recover the entire folder, the only way is select Restore all files.